# What is the mean of (ë|e) in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a simple array in JAVA:
 `private final String[] arr = {"ty(ë|e)p(ë|e)", "adlj(ë|e)na"}`
My simple question is : What is the mean of (ë|e) in above array ?

Comment: They are just characters in a `String`, maybe intended as a regular expression.

Comment: `ë` is russian letter "yo", and `e` is russian letter "ye". So this string looks as some kind of rubbish and nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely no special meaning for `(ë|e)` in JAVA. It seems that this array is intended to be used as regular expressions to match some words. In regular expressions `(ë|e)` means: match the letter `ë` or the letter `e`. For example If you compile the string `"adlj(ë|e)na"` into a regular expression, it will match either words: `adljëna` or `adljena`.

Answer (score 1):

In some Slavic languages it is common to write 'e' instead of 'ë'. As it was mentioned in the comments, it means that your expression will match the words whether they are written with 'e' or 'ë'.

Comment: Only if it used as regular expression which is not the case in the part he has shown

Answer (score 0):

No special meaning involved. Those things are just part of the Strings that are defined there literally.